# Asparagalist for "orchid fancier"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for an "orchid fancier". That is someone who likes and collects orchids.  I am pretty sure this is no existing word so I thought I would invent one. If a lepidopterist is a butterfly fancier then how about asparagalist for an orchid fancier?

Comment: Wouldn't it be an *orchidophile*?

Comment: *Orchid* is not applied to any member of the order *Asparagales* outside of the family *Orchidaceae*, so a term for an orchid enthusiast would not be derived from the name of the order— it would be like calling enthusiasts of raccoons *carnivorists*. Note that taxonomic classification is independent of whether a common name exists for a particular type of organism or not, and increasingly so as science advances and organisms are reclassified.

Comment: @choster: ... or snake enthusiasts _herpetologists_. Wait, that would be like an orchidophile being an _Asparagales_ enthusiast. Well, you get the idea.

Comment: The main issue with my suggestion is that Lepidoptera covers only butterflies and moths where Asparagales covers much more than orchids.  I am not sure why the downvote though. Is the question unsuitable in some way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The existing word is **Orchidist**.

From reading a few links provided by [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=orchidist), is seems to be used by Orchid fanciers, and even appears in my 1976 Concise Oxford.

Answer (score -1):

The Latin genus is *orchidaceae*. *Orchidaceous* denotes plants of the orchid family. And *orchidology* is the study of orchids.

So what has 'asparagalist' got to do with orchids. it seems as if it should be related to asparagus, but its family is Liliaceae.

So no, I don't think much of the idea.

Comment: The order asparagales now includes the family orchidaceae.  The genus for which the family is named is Orchis.  The liliaceae family is in another new order, liliales.  These changes reflect DNA analysis.  If you think these changes are bunk, I couldn't agree more; however, the science is sound. I've been an orchidist since the middle of the last century, so I can vouch for that word.

Comment: @Michael Owen Sartin In that case I shall, in due course delete my comment. Apologies to the OP.